# maven: specify package output location

Tags: maven, package

I have a pom file with a custom profile like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>openshift</id>
    <build>
        <finalName>pomtest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                    <warName>ROOT</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

when I execute

```
mvn war:war -Popenshift
```

it correctly generates a ROOT.war in the webapps folder

but when I execute

mvn package -Popenshift

it generates the war file in /home/sas/Ubuntu

(Ubuntu is not a folder, is the name of ht ROOT.war file)

how can I tell package the output location of the package output?

--

edit: I tried with wemu anser with no luck

just in case someone finds it useful, I'm posting the whole pom file here

it's just the pom generated by grails with grails pom-generate xxx
plus the openshift profile

--

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>com.pomtest</groupId>
        <artifactId>pomtest</artifactId>
        <packaging>grails-app</packaging>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <name>pomtest</name>
        <description>pomtest</description>

        <properties>
            <grails.version>2.1.1</grails.version>
        </properties>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                <artifactId>grails-plugin-testing</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>${grails.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <type>zip</type>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>resources</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.grails.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <type>zip</type>
        </dependency>

        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <!-- trying to set output to webapps/ROOT.war... with no luch so far -->
            <directory>${project.basedir}/webapps</directory>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/webapps</outputDirectory>
            <pluginManagement />

            <plugins>
                <!-- Disables the Maven surefire plugin for Grails applications, as we have our own test runner -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>surefire-it</id>
                            <phase>integration-test</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <skip>false</skip>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <filesets>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>plugins</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>**/*</include>
                                </includes>
                                <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                            </fileset>
                        </filesets>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
                    <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${grails.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                        <fork>true</fork>
                    </configuration>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>grails</id>
                <name>grails</name>
                <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/core</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>grails-plugins</id>
                <name>grails-plugins</name>
                <url>http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>tools</id>
                <activation>
                    <property>
                        <name>java.vendor</name>
                        <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
                    </property>
                </activation>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                        <version>${java.version}</version>
                        <scope>system</scope>
                        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </profile>

            <profile>
                <id>openshift</id>
                <build>
                    <finalName>pomtest</finalName>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                                <warName>ROOT</warName>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>

        </profiles>
    </project>
```

--

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to reconfigure the build.directory folder:

```
<build>
    <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
</build>
```

Note that not all directories can be changed within profiles: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Directories

But it may be enough to use available properties or own ones http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide to configure the build to work it the way you want it to.

The default value of warName is already: ${project.build.finalName} - so instead of using pomtest in your example you could use ROOT there as well.
Why stuff ends up in "/home/sas/Ubuntu" at all is hard to tell from the plugin config only.

regards
werner

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, werner. I tried with what you said, but with no luck. I'm posting the whole pom file.